# Python fake Java-style Package import by using the PEP 302 Importer Protocol

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I'm trying to implement the Importer Protocol as specified in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) to create a Java-style Package importer mechanism. This has the advantage that the package namespaces can be merged *virtually* but are in fact not merged physically.

Let's assume that there are two directory names listed on `sys.path` that both contain a folder `org`. Both folders however have different contents.

**Folder 1**

```
org/
    a_module.py
```

**Folder 2**

```
org/
    a_package/
        __init__.py
        tools.py
```

Now, from Python code, I want to write the following to be able to import both, `a_module` and `a_package.tools` into my Python program.

```
sys.meta_path.append(PackageImporter('org'))
import org.a_module
import org.a_package.tools as tools
```

Now, the strange problem I'm encountering is, that importing the `os` module from a package that is loaded via my custom loader, I get `ImportError: no module name path`. I can import a whole lot of other packages without problem, though!

For instance, `org/a_module.py`

```
# file: org/a_module.py
import os
```

And `test.py`

```
# file: test.py
sys.meta_path.append(PackageImporter())
import org.a_module # ImportError: no module named path
```

How can I solve this problem?

#### Implementation

The code is a bit lengthy unfortunately.

```
import os
import sys
import imp

class PackageImporter(object):

    def trace_module(self, dirname, parts):
        r""" Traces a module by the specified import *parts*. Returns
        the full path to the module that is to be imported. Directories
        will later by imported by the EmptyModuleLoader class and files
        by the ModuleLoader class. """

        for part in parts[:-1]:
            dirname = os.path.join(dirname, part)
            if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
                return None

        directory = os.path.join(dirname, parts[-1])
        modulefile = os.path.join(dirname, '%s.py' % parts[-1])
        initfile = os.path.join(directory, '__init__.py')

        if os.path.isfile(modulefile):
            return modulefile
        elif os.path.isfile(initfile):
            return initfile
        elif os.path.isdir(directory):
            return directory
        else:
            return None

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if path is None:
            path = sys.path

        parts = fullname.split('.')
        fullpath = None
        for dirname in path:
            fullpath = self.trace_module(dirname, parts)
            if fullpath:
                break

        if fullpath:
            if os.path.isdir(fullpath):
                return EmptyModuleLoader()
            else:
                return ModuleLoader(fullpath)

        return None

class EmptyModuleLoader(object):

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        mod = sys.modules.setdefault(fullname, imp.new_module(fullname))
        mod.__file__ = '<lazy package>'
        mod.__package__ = fullname
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__path__ = sys.path
        return mod

class ModuleLoader(object):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        mod = sys.modules.get(fullname)
        if mod:
            return mod

        description = ('.py', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE)
        with open(self.filename) as fp:
            mod = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, self.filename, description)

        mod.__file__ = self.filename
        mod.__loader__ = self
        if os.path.basename(self.filename) == '__init__.py':
            mod.__package__ = fullname
            mod.__path__ = sys.path
        else:
            mod.__package__ = fullname.rpartition('.')[0]

        return mod

sys.meta_path.append(PackageImporter())

import org
import org.a_module
import org.a_package.tools as tools
```

The above code is a shortened form of the current implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/nr-libs/pkgimp-py). The state at which this question was formulated is [c77c1d4e](https://github.com/nr-libs/pkgimp-py/tree/c77c1d4ec1442f9134b68a57c3371ca6541afd07).

#### Update

The most confusing fact for me is, that my Importer is not even queried for `os.path`, but instead I get *fullname* values for `org.posixpath` and `org.genericpath`??

```
def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
    if 'path' in fullname:
        print "="*40
        print fullname
        print "="*40
```

```
Niklass-MacBook-Air:Desktop niklas$ python test.py 
========================================
org.posixpath
========================================
========================================
org.genericpath
========================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 94, in <module>
    import org.a_module
  File "test.py", line 79, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, self.filename, description)
  File "/Users/niklas/Desktop/org/a_module.py", line 2, in <module>
    import os
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 120, in <module>
    from os.path import (curdir, pardir, sep, pathsep, defpath, extsep, altsep,
ImportError: No module named path
```

#### (bad) Workaround

For now, I've added the statement

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

into the source before executing the Python module which fixes the problem. But it doesn't sound like a very good approach.

Comment: Are you aware that this feature is going to be implemented in python3.4?

Comment: @Bakuriu No, I am not, thank you for the info. I still want to do it in Python 2, though.